# What's a simple symmetric way to encrypt a string and pass through a url in php?

Tags: php, url, encryption, obfuscation, encryption-symmetric

As the question states, I need a way to encrypt a string (i.e. 'x=27&y=3&z=123456' into 'hUIgBG5664y65H2UIB') so that it can be passed via an html image source, like so:

```
<img src="returnpicture.php?stuff=hUIgBG5664y65H2UIB"/>
```

returnpicture.php will decrypt that back into 'x=27&y=3&z=123456' and parse it into three variables which will be used to pick an image and return it.

Problem is, everywhere I look, all I can find is stuff about hashing and encrypting super-sensitive information like credit cards and passwords.  This info is not sensitive at all, I just don't want users to be able to tamper with it.  Therefore, it shouldn't be excessively long.  Also, the encryption (I'm guessing) must be alphanumeric, so as not to mess up the url with & or =.  I'm doing this in php.

It's for a sort of game.  The user shouldn't be able to mess with the variables, 'cause they'll see things they shouldn't yet.

Comment: "This info is not sensitive at all, I just don't want users to be able to tamper with it.", if it's not sensitive, then why do you care if it's tampered with?  If you don't care if they can read it, but you care that they modify it, then look into HMAC.

Comment: In an application at our site, we just use base64 for this.

Comment: Use a token/nonce then. Store the actual numbers in your database, and give out a random id.

Comment: If you use an encryption that's not alphanumeric, just wrap it with `urlencode()` to deal with that.

Comment: Why do you need encryption at first place? Why not pass parameters as-is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262109/php-simplest-two-way-encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For general understanding**

When you include certain key-value pairs in your request url, PHP will load these values (accordingly) into the `$_GET` superglobal.

```
?x=12&y=13
```

Will result in

```
$_GET['x'] // contains 12
$_GET['y'] // contains 13
```

What you seem to be trying to do is to supply multiple key-value pairs within a key-value pair:

```
?stuff={more-key-value-pairs}
```

Simply be aware that PHP will not interpret key-value pairs in `$_GET['stuff']`.

**Encoding/Decoding**

Note: This is one possible solution out of many. Find the one that suits you most and apply it.

You can use [base64_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) to encode it, and [base64_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) to decode it.

Example:

```
echo '<img src="returnpicture.php?stuff=' . rawurlencode( base64_encode('x=27&y=3&z=123456') ) . '" />';
```

Usage of `rawurlencode()` assures proper url safe encoding of the base64-encoded string.

In your *returnpicture.php* you can use:

```
$decodedString = base64_decode( $_GET['stuff'] );
```

to get back your original string.

However, if you actually plan on sending a get-request like string (with variable assignments, such as `?x=12&y=13` and so on, then you need to apply further techniques to get that string parsed.

[See this question for details on how it can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138999/)

Comment: `base64` is not an encryption though

Comment: You are right. Given the title of the question i assume that the OP is not actually looking for an encryption but for a way to mask his parameters; using the term `encryption` for the lack of a better word. Might be a false assumption of course. In any case the provided solution may still suit his needs and if it does not, it still hopefully adds to general understanding.

Comment: It seems to me that he's just looking for obfuscation, not encryption. He said it's not sensitive, he just doesn't want it easily tampered with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple cipher, like a rolling XOR hash. This is very easy to implement, but enough of a nuisance to crack that people probably won't bother if the only benefit is something trivial, like the ability to get your server to serve images in non-standard sizes.

```
function scramble(key, text) {
    return encodeURIComponent(text.replace(/[^\0]/g, function(x, i) {
        var code = x.charCodeAt(0) ^ key.charCodeAt(i % key.length);
        return String.fromCharCode(code);
    }));
}

function descramble(key, text) {
    return decodeURIComponent(text).replace(/[^\0]/g, function(x, i) {
        var code = x.charCodeAt(0) ^ key.charCodeAt(i % key.length);
        return String.fromCharCode(code);
    });
}
```

If your `key` is "secretcode" and your `text` is "x=27&y=3&z=123456", then `scramble(key, text)` returns "%0BXQEC%0D%5E%5CB%1FNTQAQAU".

"Descrambling" that result with the same `key` gives the original `text`, "x=27&y=3&z=123456".

Note that you'd probably want to do this on the PHP side of things, the JavaScript code is just here as an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/m92rc/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you can share information between your pages with `$_SESSION` vars, but, it only works if two pages are in same context server.

**Approach 1.** `base64` encode

```
<img src="returnpicture.php?stuff=<?php echo base64_encode('x=27&y=3&z=123456'); ?>"/>
```

And get this as:

```
$data = base64_decode($_GET['stuff']);
```

**Approach 2.** `$_SESSION` variables

You should combine **`$_GET`** with **`$_POST`** without expose sensible information like:

```
$postfix = uniqid(); // Generate an UNIQUE id
$_SESSION['sensible_var1_'.$postfix] = "value";
$_SESSION['sensible_var2_'.$postfix] = "value";
$_SESSION['sensible_var3_'.$postfix] = "value";
```

And you can pass this information only with:

```
<img src="returnpicture.php?stuff=<?php echo $postfix; ?>"/>
```

And in your **returnpicture.php** file, you can retrive information as:

```
$sensible_var1 = $_SESSION['sensible_var1_'.$_GET['stuff']];
$sensible_var2 = $_SESSION['sensible_var2_'.$_GET['stuff']];
$sensible_var3 = $_SESSION['sensible_var3_'.$_GET['stuff']];
```

Comment: If the page can have multiple of these images, each with different parameters, how would this work?